# How to properly override function with different arguments in derived class?

Tags: c++, class, parameters, derived-class

I'm making a simple MVC example for c++ classes at my uni. First, look at the code:
The executor.h part:

```
    class IExecutor {
    IParams params;
public:
    virtual void initialize(IParams iParams);
    virtual void execute();
};

class QEExec : public IExecutor {
public:
    void initialize(QEParams iParams) override;
    void execute() override;
};
```

And now params.h part:

```
class IParams {

};

class QEParams : public IParams {
public:
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};
```

The problem is that I want to create `void initialize(QEParams iParams)` function for `QEExec` and pass `QEParams` to it in order to have access to a, b, and c parameters (I'll need that later) but I can't do so because of `virtual void initialize(IParams)`. I thought that if `QEParams` is derives from `IParams` I will be able to do so, but I can't access parameters that I mentioned earlier. How to make it work so that I'll be able to access a, b and c parameters in initialize function?
EDIT: I'll put a photo of how it should look like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWaSQ.jpg

Comment: Declare the parameter as having a referenced type.

Comment: You mean parameter in IExecutor or QEexec? Because I tried adding reference and still it throws an type mismatch error.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow That doesn't work: https://godbolt.org/z/2qnuB_

Comment: What do you expect to happen if I have a `IExecutor* ex = new QEExec();` and call `ex->initialize(myIParams);`? Your interface for `IExecutor` says I can do that! What is the reason that you want the apparent requirement "derived classes must use something derived from `IParams` for initialization"?

Comment: This isn't an override, because the it's a different type. Someone could write: `IExecutor *i = new QEExec; IParams p; i->initialize(p);` and what would it do?

Comment: Why `initialize` method instead of regular constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Interface doesn't have any fields
2. Interface has only pure virtual methods
3. Name `initialize` of `IExecutor` indicates some misunderstanding. Looks like it suppose to be called once at the begging during construction time. It should be hidden in step where some factory creates object implementing `IExecutor`

So basically I'm suspecting you need more something like this:

```cpp
class IExecutor
{
public:
    virutal ~IExecutor() {}
    virtual void execute() = 0;
};

struct QEParams {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

class QEExec: public IExecutor
{
public:
    QEExec(int b, int c) ....

    void initialie(); // second step init

    void execute() override;
};

class CAExec: public SomeOtherBaseClass, public IExecutor
{
public:
    CAExec(int a, int c) ....

    void execute() override;
};

std::unique_ptr<IExecutor> executorFactory(const QEParams& params)
{
    if (params.a < 0) {
        auto result = std::make_unique<QEExec>(params.b, params.c);
        result->initialie();
        return result;
    }
    return std::make_unique<CAExec>(params.a, params.c);
}
```

Usually factory parameters are structural data and extra abstraction is obsolete.

If different kind of arguments are needed to create alternative version of `IExecutor` you just provide different factory function (possibly overload):

```
std::unique_ptr<IExecutor> executorFactory(const std::string& fileName)
{
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using OOP incorrectly.

Since `QEExec` *is a* `IExecutor` (it inherits), and it can `initialize` just like `IExecutor` can, ideally, both of those initialize's will be doing similar things to their `IParams` objects. If so, then the one who should be acting on `a`, `b` and `c` should be `QEParams`, not `QEExec`.

You could do this with polymorphism like:

```
class IParams {
    virtual void init_logic() { }
};

class QEParams : public IParams {
public:
    void init_logic() { /* Do something with a/b/c */ }
private:
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};
```

And then...

```
class IExecutor {
    IParams params;
public:
    virtual void initialize(IParams *iParams);
    virtual void execute();
};

class QEExec : public IExecutor {
public:
    //Will call the QEParams init_logic when passed a QEParams pointer
    void initialize(IParams *iParams) { iParams->init_logic(); }
    void execute() override;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. So it turns out that there is no way to define the type of object I want to pass to initialize method? I have not only QEExec and QEParams in my example and I wanted initialize methods to make some operations on different variables inside QEParams etc. and finally put them in a different form into params field of base class IExecutor because I'll need them later.

Comment: @Piston if your `QEExec` can *only* work with a `QEParams`, then it shouldn't be inheriting from `IExecutor` at all. That's what I'm trying to say here. It's not clear to me what you're trying to do, but it *is* clear that you're attempting to fight the class system because of the way you've designed and architected these classes.